# Not getting a 404 for Patch for user that does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am expecting that when I send a PATCH/update to a user that does not exist, I should get back a 404, but instead I am getting back a 200.

```
### Update a user
PATCH http://localhost:3000/auth/2345678
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "password": "letmein"
}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Date: Thu, 09 Sep 2021 19:41:13 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

In the console I do get back:

> (node:36780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NotFoundException: user
> not found
> at UsersService.update (/Users/luiscortes/Projects/car-value/src/users/users.service.ts:27:13)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created) (node:36780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:36780) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code. (node:36780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> NotFoundException: user not found
> at UsersService.update (/Users/luiscortes/Projects/car-value/src/users/users.service.ts:27:13)
> (node:36780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2)

but why don't I get a 404 in my REST Client?

This is my `users.controller.ts` file:

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Post,
  Get,
  Patch,
  Param,
  Query,
  Delete,
  NotFoundException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dtos/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dtos/update-user.dto';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Post('/signup')
  createUser(@Body() body: CreateUserDto) {
    this.usersService.create(body.email, body.password);
  }

  @Get('/:id')
  async findUser(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne(parseInt(id));
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('user not foud');
    }
    return user;
  }

  @Get()
  findAllUsers(@Query('email') email: string) {
    return this.usersService.find(email);
  }

  @Delete('/:id')
  removeUser(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.usersService.remove(parseInt(id));
  }

  @Patch('/:id')
  updateUser(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() body: UpdateUserDto) {
    this.usersService.update(parseInt(id), body);
  }
}
```

This is my `users.service.ts` file:

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private repo: Repository<User>) {}

  create(email: string, password: string) {
    const user = this.repo.create({ email, password });

    return this.repo.save(user);
  }

  findOne(id: number) {
    return this.repo.findOne(id);
  }

  find(email: string) {
    return this.repo.find({ email });
  }

  async update(id: number, attrs: Partial<User>) {
    const user = await this.findOne(id);
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('user not found');
    }
    Object.assign(user, attrs);
    return this.repo.save(user);
  }

  async remove(id: number) {
    const user = await this.findOne(id);
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('user not found');
    }
    return this.repo.remove(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot `await`ing (or alternatively `return`ing) the call to `this.usersService.update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return the service call in your path request, so Nest doesn't know to wait for it. The service code then runs in the background after the response has been sent, and causes this unhandledPromiseRejection to show up. Change your patch method to this

```js
@Patch('/:id')
updateUser(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() body: UpdateUserDto) {
  return this.usersService.update(parseInt(id), body);
}
```